# Why Angular's ng-model values are not reflected within web browser's web inspector

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering why I cannot see rendered input text values in the web browser's web inspector when data is represented by AngularJS ng-model.

Please see the following code snippet:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_databinding_ng-model

I would like to rely on the web inspector in a way to see all things I already see on the web page, however in this case `<input>` element in web inspector presents the following code without the expected text value "John":

```
<input ng-model="firstname" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty">
```

Why is that? What web browser mechanisms are working here that we see discrepancies between rendered content and web inspector content which if I am not wrong represents the same content as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Natively the value of an input is stored in the inputs node.value, it isn't something that you are going to be able to see in the elements explorer in your debugger.

There are two good ways of evaluating this,

(assuming your using chrome, I'm sure there are equivalents in other browsers)

You can use your Elements explorer to highlight the specific input node and log its value in your chrome console by typing

```
$0.value
```

$0 will be set to the node you have last highlighted in the Elements screen

You should see something like this in your console replacing my gibberish with your text value.

[image: selected node]

The second more "angular" way to accomplish this is to instead type in

```
angular.element($0).controller('ngModel').$viewValue;
```

angular.element($0) will wrap the input in a jqlite object which you can then call .controller on to get the ngModel controller of that DOM node. From there you can get the $viewValue of the input.

You can also use this to get validity and other useful bits of information that can be very helpful when writing component tests.

Comment: "Natively the value of an input is stored in the inputs node.value, it isn't something that you are going to be able to see in the elements explorer in your debugger." - of course I can natively do that just write code <input type="text" value="test" /> and use Elements tab and you can easily see it. The question was why I can't see that with Angular when I see it rendered.

Comment: Because an input doesn't need the attribute value to have a value. This is the case without AngularJS, type into an input and see that the element itself is unchanged.